# Error upgrading Magento 2.4.3-p1 to 2.4.4

Tags: magento, magento2.4

I updated PHP to 8.1 and the site from 2.4.3-p1 to 2.4.4, first on a test server and everything went well, but when I did in production the frontend is working correctly, but the backend comes in but the only link in the menu that works is the control panel itself, the others do not open (store, system, ...).
I compiled and deployed several times and it didn't work.
Files in pub/static are generated normally.
Has anyone been through this situation? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you check the console of your browser and your Magento log, do it show any bugs?